# Disqus seems to be taking longer than usual error

Tags: disqus

Does anyone got this error when using disqus?

```
Disqus seems to be taking longer than usual. Reload?
```

I got it this afternoon when i'm installing disqus in my blog 
and the browser i 'm using is firefox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This started happening to my browsers (firefox and IE) just recently. Since both browsers are displaying the same error, it had to be something in my network. We use OpenDNS to filter stuff and disqus.com was being blocked. Whitelisting disqus.com allowed the comments to load.

Comment: This helped me in resolving the issue I had the AdBlock plus extension installed on my Chrome browser, disabling the same solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've just discovered that my Internet Provider (Vodafone) are blocking Disqus at their DNS. No idea why.
Changed my DNS to point to Google and I can now load Disqus.